# Is it possible to exit a Freemarker template?

Tags: exit, template-engine, freemarker

I'd like to be able to end the page's rendering from within an <#if> tag.

I'm aware of the <#stop> tag, but I'd prefer not to have to throw an exception in order for the page to stop rendering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a dirty trick for that: Put the whole content of the template inside a macro and then immediately call that macro. Inside the macro you can use `<#return>`.

Comment: Thanks. I'd seen this trick in a forum, but it was years old and I had hoped that something more facile had come along in the meantime. It would appear not.